# FormatCondition error with Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works splendidly on Excel 2013. But on Excel 2007 I get problems.

```
Function IsMasked() As Boolean

    Dim wksTables As Worksheet
    Set wksTables = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wTables")

    Dim loMask As ListObject
    Set loMask = wksTables.ListObjects("tMask")

    Dim lor As ListRow
    For Each lor In loMask.ListRows
        Dim sWorksheetName As String
        Dim sRangeAddress As String
        Dim sCompleteAddress As String

        sWorksheetName = Intersect(lor.Range, loMask.ListColumns("Worksheet").DataBodyRange)
        sRangeAddress = Intersect(lor.Range, loMask.ListColumns("Range").DataBodyRange)

        Dim R As Range
        Set R = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sWorksheetName).Range(sRangeAddress)

        With R
            Dim bMasked As Boolean

            Dim fc As Object
                For Each fc In .FormatConditions
                    If TypeName(fc) = "FormatCondition" Then
                        If fc.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) And fc.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                            'Range has mask if any formatcondition is mask
                            bMasked = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next fc

            If bMasked = False Then
                'Mask is false if any specified range does not have mask
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next lor

    IsMasked = bMasked
End Function
```

`If fc.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) And fc.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)` evaluates to true even when the interior color is set to nothing and when the font color is red.

When I look at `fc` in the locals window a lot of the properties say `application-defined` or `object-defined error`. I don't know if this is any clue.

Comment: Did you declare the `fc` as Variant as opposed to Object?

Comment: I tried it now, but it made no difference.